# Difference between secrets.compare_digest and hmac.compare_digest

Tags: python

There are two strings comparison functions to prevent timing attacks: `secrets.compare_digest` and `hmac.compare_digest`. But it's not clear from the documentation how i should choose between them. Are they the same? If so, why is there such duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they the same?

Yes, you might check that following way

```
import hmac
import secrets
print(hmac.compare_digest is secrets.compare_digest)
```

outputs

```
True
```

or if you do not have access to Python prompt, deduce that looking at [`secrets`' source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/secrets.py) which does have following line

```
from hmac import compare_digest
```